# Porting Windows Mobile Pocket PC client to Windows CE Mobile Client

Tags: windows-ce, pocketpc

I have an Pocket PC application which is compiled with windows mobile 6 professional SDK.

Now i want the application to work with Windows CE.

What are the procedure to compile it on Windows CE and make it work on Windows CE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may sound silly or obvious, but: **Build it using the Windows CE SDK** ([download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17310)).

**Step 1:** After installing the SDK, create a new Windows CE Project.

**Step 2:** Take the blank Form1.cs form in the new CE Project and rename it to the Form you use in your old Windows Mobile 6 Project.

Almost done.

**Step 3:** Now, close Visual Studio, browse to the Windows CE Project Folder, and delete the that form you just renamed.

**Step 4:** Browse to your Windows Mobile 6 Project Folder. Copy everything **except** for the `bin` and `obj` folders and the .proj and .sln files to the Windows CE Project Folder.

**Step 5:** Open Visual Studio and the Windows CE Project.

**Step 6:** Get crazy and hit Run [F5].

This will most likely produce a number of errors. These errors are because you have called a function that is specific to Windows Mobile or it could be because the Windows CE version of the same function requires different parameters.

**Step 7:** Some things may not be easily ported to Windows CE. For those items, you can start new threads like *"How do I do FunctionWM() using Windows CE?"* or such.